# File comparer where files can be edited during compare

Tags: git, filemerge

Do you know any file merging too, where meantime I can edit files? I do not want save and reload just edit end merging would automatically reloaded.

I tried FileMerge and Kaleidoscope. None of them has this feature. For huge files it would be useful if about chunk of code merger does not realize Thea are the same, some character is changed, and I would just correct it right at that point.

Comment: [vimdiff](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/625/how-do-i-use-vim-as-a-diff-tool)

Comment: I mean an app with GUI. :D vimdiff is a terminal app, isn't it? We have 10000 line, terminal is not an option here.

Comment: I tend to use [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/). Simple, clear, does the job.